# Converting a JSON into own type results in null objects

Tags: c#, json

from my rest call, I am receiving this JSON:

```
{
  "livemode": true,
  "error": {
    "type": "unauthorized",
    "message": "You did not provide a valid API key."
  }
}
```

I need to fetch type and message into my type:

```
public class TestObject
{
    string type { get; set; }
    string message { get; set; }
}
```

But this returns null objects:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

Uri uri = new Uri("https://api.onlinebetaalplatform.nl/v1");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);

TestObject album = json.ToObject<TestObject>();
```

1.) I understand that the type and message attributes are "nested". How do I access them?
2.) Even if I call my type livemode and error, the objects still return null.

Can you help me out a little?

Thank you :)

Comment: You have invalid JSON. It's as simple as that. You have an object immediately inside an object without a property for the nested object (`{{` instead of `{ "propertyName": {`).

Comment: Also, even if you only had the nested object of `{{`, you're trying to parse "error" (a nested object itself) from the main object, rather than the nested object.

Comment: To reinforce Llama: You're JSON is in fact not valid, you can use a site like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to see if it's valid. And even if you had valid JSON (for which the double curly braces at the start and end should be replaced with only 1), you'd probably want to model the entire JSON by creating a class to represent the root object. You can use a site like [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) as a starting point of your C# code

Comment: are u refering to the two {{ in the begining? disregard those, it shouldve only been one {.

Comment: @MindSwipe THANK YOU! that helped me out a lot. Post as answer, ill accept :)

Comment: @Jay accept Eric Ruder's answer, they were faster to post it as a correct answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be one set of curly brackets to many. I am pretty sure that the api you are querying is not returning the first and the last curly bracket. Continue on after that has been taken care of.

In order to fetch the data, add these class definitions

```
public class Error
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public bool livemode { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
}
```

and change

```
TestObject album = json.ToObject<TestObject>();
```

To

```
Root album = json.ToObject<Root>();
```

As some of the comments to your question mentioned, you are currently trying to convert the JSON string to the nested Error object instead of the root object, where the Error object is located.

In the future, there are tools that can generate C# classes from JSON. I used https://json2csharp.com/ this time around to do so.

EDIT:
I just found out that Visual Studio actually has an in-built JSON to Class feature!

[image: JSON-to-csharp]

Comment: Or just `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(content);`

Comment: Please note that currently the properties of the classes aren't in line with the C# naming guidelines, they should be PascalCase, i.e have their first letter capitalised. You can use the [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) (which is also in .NET Core now [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonproperty.name?view=net-5.0)) to rename them

Comment: Yes, that would be a more optimal solution, was just trying to make it fit with his existing setup.

Comment: Also yes to @MindSwipe, you should be following C#'s naming guidelines and using PascalCase. I just took the output from a JSON to Csharp tool and pasted it in. I am pretty confident all json serializers out there support mapping going from one "case" to another.

Comment: Thank you, that was just what I was looking for as a beginner in rest calls :)